# Differentiation of a simple function

Tags: derivatives

I was studying the second derivative and got stuck with this problem.

$$y=4x-(2x-1)^4$$

I assumed that $u=(2x-1)$ and differentiate u with respect to x but for $y=4x-u^4$ how can I differentiate that?

Comment: Hint: the chain rule.

Comment: If $u=2x-1$ then $4x=2u+2$

Comment: If you know how to differentiate $f(x)=4x$ and you know how to differentiate $g(x)=(2x-1)^4$ then you know how to differentiate $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) $... right?

Comment: @Henry Oh right! I did not see that point. Thank you!

Comment: @JakeMirra Wow I can also approach the problem in this way! Thank you so much!!! Now I know the new approach!